# How to share an app via AirDrop?

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store, share, airdrop

I'm trying to share my application via AirDrop with UIActivityViewController interface.
If I pass an iTunes url, the other user gets a message "X's iPhone would like to show you an app in the App Store." without the app name and icon.

What's the right way to share the app via AirDrop (similar to sharing an app from the AppStore)?

Comment: Did you try passing a UIImage along with the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [AirDrop sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html) on how to use UIActivityItemSource. The item you would share is an NSURL, and then you can provide a thumbnail image. You will however not be able to customize the text in the alert on the receiving side.